# SSIS package throws Invalid character value for cast specification error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, etl

I am trying to create a flat file with Header and Line by querying the SQL Server Database. I am following the [link here](https://www.sqlshack.com/using-ssis-packages-to-add-row-headers-and-data-into-flat-files/) to generate the Flat File with the Header and the Line like below

```
H,123,ABC
L,I_740,A8-SH,20
L,I_913,M3-SH,20
H,144,DEF
L,I_330,E3-SH,20
L,I_738,E4-SH,20
L,I_547,M6-SH,14
```

The SSIS package looks like below

[image]

In Foreach Loop I have a the 1st Data Flow Task for generating the Header and other DataFlow task for creating the Line items. In the 1st Data Flow Task I have below action

[image]

The OLE DB Source has below query

```
SELECT DISTINCT 'H' as Header, cus.CustomerNumber as CustomerNumber, mo.UserFullName as UserFullName
  FROM [dbo].[MouseOrder] mo
  JOIN [dbo].[Customer] cus on cus.Customer_ID = [CustomerId]
  JOIN [dbo].[InventoryOrder] io on io.OrderId = mo.MouseOrder_ID 
  JOIN [dbo].[Inventory] i on i.Inventory_ID = io.InventoryId
  where mo.OrderDate = convert(varchar, dateadd(hour,-5,GETUTCDATE()), 23) and  cus.CustomerNumber = ? and mo.UserFullName =?
```

When I try to run my package it throws error on the OLE DB Source action

`Error: 0xC0202009 at Data Flow Task, OLE DB Source [14]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21. An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification". Error: 0xC004701A at Data Flow Task, SSIS.Pipeline: OLE DB Source failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0x80040E21.`

[image]

Can anyone please suggest what is the  I am missing here

**EDIT**

[image]

Comment: Is your column `OrderDate` *really* a `varchar`? If so, it isn't a date, it's a string. That's a design flaw you should be fixing.

Comment: @Larnu `OrderDate` is a date column. When I run this query in SSMS it works fine.. I have updated my question

Comment: If it's a date, why are you comparing it to a `varchar`? Surely a `date` would be a better choice, no?

Comment: I googled that up I wanted to check if the OrderDate is equal to the current date in EST.. And it was working so I just started using that

Comment: As for the error, it's saying you're trying to convert something in your Source. Presumably you've defined a column within the source with a different data type to that in your table, and it can't be implicitly cast.

Comment: @Larnu Can you please help me how can I check `OrderDate`  to todays date in EST without converting to varchar

Comment: `CONVERT(date...` Also note that -5 hours means that the expression will always expect Eastern Standard Time; it won't handle locations that change to Eastern Daylight Time (EDT).

Comment: @Larnu Thank you even after changing that I am getting the same error

Comment: @Larnu is there a way to check both EDT and EST at the same time

Comment: Well yes, you haven't addressed the actual problem, just the confusion in that your `WHERE` makes it appear that your column is a `varchar`. I cover the error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70098319/ssis-package-throws-invalid-character-value-for-cast-specification-error#comment123914743_70098319).

Comment: *"is there a way to check both EDT and EST at the same time"* That is a different question to what you are asking here.

Comment: @Larnu Found the issue `and  cus.CustomerNumber = ? and mo.UserFullName =?` in the where clause .. I tried to same way as suggested in the https://www.sqlshack.com/using-ssis-packages-to-add-row-headers-and-data-into-flat-files/